# Unable to extract the array field from JSON file. Instead my code returns "{}"

Tags: javascript, json

I want to return (res.json) the array of chats in this model but when I am trying to do so I am getting "{}".

On the other hand, when I am printing other fields like email or first_name, I am getting the results.
However, I guess the problem is only with arrays.
I am using MongoDB to store data and Postman for requests

PLEASE HELP!

Here is my JSON model.

```js
{
        "_id": "5f0d5ea45eeeaa3730eaf96c",
        "first_name": "Test_firstName",
        "last_name": "Test_lastName",
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$B8EDo3KkJZ9PjGveWfouM.1XhaPSx9xrM3c6Mk2HC02AUNnO99Of.",
        "address": "Home",
        "chats": [
            {
                "id": "985234e2-86c6-4375-968a-96661c37ec32",
                "name": "Community",
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "id": "35c7bf4d-e556-40bd-9429-16e436c599f4",
                        "time": "11:10",
                        "message": "Hi",
                        "sender": "user1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "a74ad9ba-44b9-43af-90a0-cf9480d9a748",
                        "time": "11:11",
                        "message": "hey",
                        "sender": "user2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-07-14T07:28:36.148Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-07-14T07:28:36.148Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Here is my code to find a chat from my model.
Please have a look at the lines with "<"

```js
const find_chat = (req, res, next) => {
  let email = req.body.email;
  let chatId = req.body.chatId;
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .then(async (response) => {
      

> let x = [];
>           x = response.chats;
>           res.json({
>             response,
>           });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.json({
        message: "An error occured",
      });
    });
};
```

Here is the expected output

```js
{
                [
                    {
                        "id": "35c7bf4d-e556-40bd-9429-16e436c599f4",
                        "time": "11:10",
                        "message": "Hi",
                        "sender": "Advait"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "a74ad9ba-44b9-43af-90a0-cf9480d9a748",
                        "time": "11:11",
                        "message": "hey",
                        "sender": "sharma"
                    }
                ]
}
```

Comment: by printing I mean using res.json

Comment: what you need to get , messages ?

Comment: the whole array of chats  or messages ? or the json to array ? if its not clear you can add an expected o/p

Comment: I need the messages array.

Comment: please could you add what would be the expected o/p ?

Comment: yes adding it. sorry for not putting it up earlier

Comment: just added it. please have a look

Comment: no worries that would be easy for others to answer , please look at the answer and let me know if any comments you want to put

Answer (score 0):

You could try as this:

```js
const data = {
        "_id": "5f0d5ea45eeeaa3730eaf96c",
        "first_name": "Test_firstName",
        "last_name": "Test_lastName",
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$B8EDo3KkJZ9PjGveWfouM.1XhaPSx9xrM3c6Mk2HC02AUNnO99Of.",
        "address": "Home",
        "chats": [
            {
                "id": "985234e2-86c6-4375-968a-96661c37ec32",
                "name": "Community",
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "id": "35c7bf4d-e556-40bd-9429-16e436c599f4",
                        "time": "11:10",
                        "message": "Hi",
                        "sender": "user1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "a74ad9ba-44b9-43af-90a0-cf9480d9a748",
                        "time": "11:11",
                        "message": "hey",
                        "sender": "user2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-07-14T07:28:36.148Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-07-14T07:28:36.148Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
    
    let messages = data.chats[0].messages;
    console.log(messages)
```

As per the later query , change it to

```
 let x = JSON.stringify(response.chats[0].messages);
 res.json({
response});
```

Comment: actually this model is stored in the database. So I guess I need to make changes in the other code

Comment: so whats in `response` you could assign to a variable and same as i did , i could help only if we know whats is in response

Comment: I am doing that but it is returning this -  "{}"

Comment: for the other fields like first_name and last_name, it is working correctly

Comment: i have updated the answer , please look in to it -- 4 lines ">" that u mentioned

Comment: nope its not working it went into the catch part and returned "{
    "message": "An error occured"
}"

Comment: i understood as in `x` you want to get an array of messages so for that u could directly do as i mentioned

Comment: Yes i know it should work but idk why its not working

Comment: uf .. i can't know why it is not coming but only thing i could say is get messages as in x , also where is `x` used ?

Comment: for others its working. Like if I try to get email. I am writing  let x = response.email;
 res.json({
response});

Comment: and its giving the required output

Comment: replaced x with response , once check it , i have updated in answer , though it's confusing

Comment: when i do this I get the model (the first code spinnet I posted).

Comment: well , this could be due to JSON format issue , i will have another try , updated the answer , im not sure of placing response , please also try keeping x in response place

Comment: sorry man it went into the catch part again. I guess it is not accepting response.chats as an array

Comment: sorry couldn't help you